# JSON Object returns a null pointer

Tags: java, android, json, android-manifest

I want to insert some items into the database. In the main activity, I retrieve information from the user and pass it to the another class to do some parsing. My JSONObject keeps showing up as NULL.

I am sorry if I am not clear with the question . I've tried to explain it as much as possible.

Below is the code your inputs are welcome

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** THE FOLLOWING STRINGS WILL BE DISPLAYED IN LOGCAT */

final String TAG = "########-------MAIN ACTIVITY: LOGIN--------######";
final String URL = "http://46.51.193.32/timereport/ses/sessions";
UserHelper userAdapter;
UserHelper db;
EditText edit_password,edit_username,edit_company;
String regName;
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    db = new UserHelper(this);
    userAdapter = new UserHelper(this);
     edit_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
     edit_username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
     edit_company = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.company_string);
    Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
            try{

                JSONObject subJson = new JSONObject();
                subJson.put("username", edit_username.getText().toString());
                subJson.put("password", edit_password.getText().toString());
                subJson.put("company", edit_company.getText().toString());
                jsonobj.put("user", subJson);
            }
            catch(JSONException e) {
                Log.i("","#####-----error at catch jsonexception-----#####");

            }
HandleJSON.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonobj);
                String regNameSplit[] = regName.split("-");
            try{
                userAdapter.openDatabase();
                long id = db.insertIntoDatabase(edit_username.getText().toString(),edit_company.getText().toString(), edit_password.getText().toString(),regNameSplit[0], regNameSplit[2]);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have successfully logged in as: " +"\n" +regNameSplit[0], duration).show();
                Log.i(TAG, "Printing value of id which will be inserted only to remove warnings "+id);
                userAdapter.closeDatabase();
            }
            catch(SQLiteException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

}

This is the class to which I am sending the JSON object to be parsed

```
public class HandleJSON{

UserHelper userAdapter;
private static final String TAG = "&&----HTTPClient-----**";
public static String SendHttpPost (String URL, JSONObject jsonobj) {
String regName = "";

try{    

        Log.v("Json object request is ",jsonobj.toString());
        DefaultHttpClient httpClientInstance = GetHttpClient.getHttpClientInstance();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);
        Log.v(TAG,"The url is "+URL);

        StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());

        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClientInstance.execute(httpPostRequest);
        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPRESPONSE RECIEVED" +(System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms");

            String resultString = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            Log.v(TAG , "The response is " +resultString);
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(resultString);
            JSONObject sessionJson = jsonObj.getJSONObject("session");
            String sessionId = sessionJson.getString("sessionid");
            String name = sessionJson.getString("name");
            Log.v(TAG,"The session ID is "+sessionId);
            Log.v(TAG,"The name is "+name);
            regName = name+"-"+sessionId+"-"+URL;

} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return regName;
}

 private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;
try{
    while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null ){
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
}
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
 }
 }
```

I've just added some of the code that was missing at the MainActivity,

```
String regNameSplit[] = regName.split("-");
```

keeps showing up as null

Comment: try printing the json String before , HandleJSON.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonobj); , i think you might be hitting the exception, in which case jsonobj will be null.

Comment: By "keeps showing up as NULL" do you mean that the jsonobj argument inside `SendHttpPost` is null? BTW the `Log.v("Json object request is ",jsonobj.toString());` looks a bit weird did you mean `Log.v("Json object request is " + jsonobj.toString());`?

Comment: He probably meant `Log.v(TAG, "Json object request is " + jsonobj);`

Comment: You are not using result of `SendHttpPost()` method. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with this, could you tell me what is the use of regname ?

at your mainactivity just change the following:

```
regname = HandleJSON.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonobj);
```

Your not calling back regname to be assigned to name and sessionid that you are returning at the sendhttppost.

Answer (score 2):

1. Instead of your `convertStreamToString()` method try using system provided [`EntityUtils.toString(entity)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29).
2. IMPORTANT: do not catch generic `Exception`, this hides unchecked (runtime) exceptions. You might be hiding the `JSONException` that happens in [JSONObject constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29).

**Update:**

You are calling `SendHttpPost` and not assigning result to variable:

```
HandleJSON.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonobj);
```

should be:

```
regName = HandleJSON.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonobj);
```

Comment: ... and don't ever `printStackTrace()` when logging is so readily available as in Android's `Log` class. `printStackTrace()` cuts off stack traces and has a talent of doing it to exactly the interesting parts.